# SQL WITH clause doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, with-statement

I'm trying to execute seemingly simple request contains `WITH` clause:

```
WITH sub AS (SELECT url FROM site WHERE id = 15) 
SELECT * FROM search_result WHERE url = sub.url
```

But it doesn't work. I get

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "sub"

What's the matter?

Comment: Your Postgres version?

Comment: Is there any requirement to use the with clause?

Comment: My PostgreSQL version is 9.1

Comment: @Ryan Gates Yes, `WITH` clause is required to use. My real query is much more complex and confusing. So I'm trying to execute this simple request to understand how it should be used and what is wrong with it.

Comment: What is the difference between using the `WITH` clause and an inner join for the logic in your question? Or logic that you have omitted?

Comment: Logic is that the `SELECT` with `WITH` statement performed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table expressions need to be used like tables.  You're trying to use the value of sub as a scalar.

Try this (forgive me, Postgres is not my first SQL dialect).

```
WITH sub AS (SELECT url FROM site WHERE id = 15) 
SELECT * FROM sub
INNER JOIN
 search_result 
ON
  sub.url = search_result.url
```

EDIT, alternatively, you could just skip the WITH clause and go with:-

```
SELECT * FROM 
  site
INNER JOIN
  search_result 
ON
  site.url = search_result.url
WHERE 
  site.id = 15
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** use a CTE at all for this simple case.
Unlike you seem to be expecting, the following simple query *without* a CTE will be slightly **faster**:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM   search_result r
JOIN   site s USING (url)
WHERE  s.id = 15;
```

Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to verify.

CTEs introduce an ***optimization barrier***. They have many very good uses, but they won't make simple queries faster.
Here is a [thread on pgsql-performance](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4EA6E252.6030002@linos.es#4EA6E252.6030002@linos.es) that gives you more details as to why that is.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to use a CTE:

```
With sub as (
    SELECT url
    FROM site
    WHERE id = 15
)
SELECT * 
FROM Search_Result SR 
   JOIN sub ON SR.url = sub.Url
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just as easily do an inner join:

```
SELECT search_result .* 
FROM
    search_result
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT url FROM site WHERE id = 15) as st
ON
    search_result.url = st.url
```

This does the filtering so that you are joining on a smaller set than if you did the where clause outside of the filtering. This may not matter in your case, but it is something to consider.